# How can I alter Easy Breadcrumb?

Tags: 8, breadcrumbs

I want to remove certain element of breadcrumb on certain condition. I tried `theme_preprocess_breadcrumb($variables)`. The condition and logic works fine here but doesn't reflect on viewing page. I tried this `module_system_breadcrumb_alter(\Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb &$breadcrumb)` – same issue. Code here doesn't reflect on viewing page, though printing variables in both methods gives me expected result but not on viewing page. I need help.

```
function theme_preprocess_breadcrumb($variables) {
// Removing last element of breadcrumb
if ( $variables['breadcrumb'] ) {  
$currentUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
$key = 'find this';  
$countElements = count($variables['breadcrumb']);
if (strpos($currentUrl, $key) == true) {
  unset($variables['links'][$countElements-1]);
  unset($variables['breadcrumb'][$countElements-1]);
  kint($variables['breadcrumb']);kint($variables);die; 
}
}
return $variables;
}
```

Comment: Maybe start by explaining what breadcrumb you have right now, and what breadcrumb exactly you want. Then also include the code that didn't work. Please edit your question accordingly. Many thanks

Comment: I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb i want to remove some element on certain condition logic is build and works well if i use above mention hooks and print the variable there. But it doesnt applies on viewing the page.

Comment: This this out https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288635/getting-call-to-a-member-function-getname-on-null-in-custom-breadcrumb/288639#288639 there is two ways to alter breadcrumb, otherwise if you have specific use case, as @leymannx mentioned in comment add your code that doesn't work !

Comment: I want to remove the breadcrumb last element on the condition mentioned in the function above what wrong i am doing here?

Comment: You should read the documentation for PHP's `strpos` function

Comment: You are not passing variables by reference. So the array is not being modified.

Comment: But when i am printing the variable in the last line it gives me desired result here.

Comment: It doesn't matter there, you need to specify the argument as &$variables as the hook documentation states. There is no return, it is modified in place.

Comment: Again, you need to add the & pass by reference, NOT a return. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209231/breadcrumb-preprocess-from-module

Comment: As far as I remember Easy Breadcrumb offered a setting to exclude the current page from the trail, no?

Comment: @leymannx Yes but i want wanted it to exclude on certain condition not for all pages.

Comment: @Kevin thanks it worked. for now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it mentioned in the comment section the `$variables` should passed by reference take a look at [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) documentation page.
And also read about [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php) to adapt your condition, here is an example of code to remove the last breadcrumb element in case url contain the word ***article*** for instance.

```
/**
 * Implements hook__preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  // Removing the last element of the breadcrumb
  if ($variables['breadcrumb']) {
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    // Get the real path even if it has an alias.
    $real_path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
    $key = 'article';
    if (strpos($real_path, $key)) {
      // Remove the last element.
      array_pop($variables['breadcrumb']);
    }
  }
}
```